# TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type in python

Tags: python

I have an list and through a for loop I must calculate the number of words in that list that have more than five letters and print the number.

but I have an error that is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5444/3081067402.py in <module>
      7 for i in words:
      8     if len(words)>5:
----> 9         more_than_five.append(words.sum(i))
     10 
     11 print(more_than_five)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     45 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     46          initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 47     return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     48 
     49 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

this is my code:

```
list_countries = 'Japan, Singapore, Maldives, Europe, Italy, Korea'
words = np.array(list_countries.split())

more_than_five = []

for i in words:
    if len(words)>5:
        more_than_five.append(words.sum(i))

print(more_than_five)
```

What is causing this error? Can someone help me to correct it?

For example:
`list_countries = 'Japan, Singapore, Maldives, Europe, Italy, Korea` 
the expected output is: 3

Because there are only three words that have more than 5 letters, Singapore, Maldives and Europe.

but instead I get the error that I named them.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a NumPy array for this, rather than a standard Python list? Especially if you're just starting out with Python, it's probably better to learn the basic data types first before adding complex third-party libraries.

Comment: @LinaSofia I'm sorry, but that makes even less sense to use a `numpy.ndarray` instead of a `list` object. In any case, it isn't clear what you expect `words.sum(i)` to do. The error is telling you that `numpy` doesn't understand either.

Comment: Why do you *want* to put in `more_than_five`? You haven't actually told us. Do you want the word? Because then it would just be `more_than_five.append(i)` and note, your condition is probably supposed to be `if len(i) > 5`, where `i` is the word, and you want to create a list with words from the original list that have more than 5 characters

Answer (score 2):

First, what you called a list is in fact a string, so you have to change this string into a list

Then,if you just want the number of words that have more than five letters, "more_than_five" should be an "int"

Here is my proposition:

```
import numpy as np

list_countries = 'Japan, Singapore, Maldives, Europe, Italy, Korea'
list_countries = list_countries.replace(' ', '').split(',')

more_than_five = 0

for words in list_countries:
    if len(words) > 5:
        more_than_five += 1

print(more_than_five)
```

The output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re using numpy.Array.sum, when you could just find the length of a normal python list, without numpy.

The easiest fix to preserve what you have would be to only do `more_than_5.append(i)`, then calculate the sum at the end.

However, you could also do:

```
list_countries = 'Japan, Singapore, Maldives, Europe, Italy, Korea'

print(len(list(filter(lambda i: len(i)>5, list_countries.split(", ")))))
```

This is essentially the same thing, just shortened down

Comment: you *could* do that but `filter` isn't very Pythonic. And in this case, creating a list just to get the length is unnecessarily inefficient. If you *wanted to be terse* (for some reason) then you could do something like `sum(len(word) > 5 for word in list_countries.split(", "))`but really, just a simple for-loop is fine

Comment: I really appreciate your proposal, but I can't do it with lambda, it must be with a for loop. @Anonymous4045

Comment: @LinaSofia Ah, okey, try just changing what I put first then. First, ditch numpy. Then, instead of `more_than_five.append(words.sum(i))`, use `more_than_five.append(i)`. Then, you simply do `len(more_than_five)` to get how many words mit the criteria 

Answer (score 0):

Although you've already gotten great solutions to this problem, I thought I'd chime in on what the error means if you run across it in the future. Basically, anytime Python throws a 'TypeError' it means it has ran across a type that confuses it in the given context. In your problem, python is expecting an 'int' or 'float' for the function words.sum(i). However, you have given it a 'str' type, which can't be used for mathematical operations.

Hope this helps in the future!